# Unmet dependencies for cups when running apt-get upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

When I ran `sudo apt-get update` it shows the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http ://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http ://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http ://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                 
Hit:4 http ://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease               
Fetched 102 kB in 2s (51.1 kB/s)                             
Reading package lists... Done
```

After that when I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` it shows:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2)
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2)
 cups-daemon : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Any solution?

Comment: What happens when you run the suggested command

`apt-get -f install` (no other options)

Comment: when i run apt-get -f install .....it shows:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cups : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2)
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2)
 cups-daemon : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 libwxbase3.0-0v5-dbg : Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (= 3.0.2+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 1):

Run `dpkg -l | egrep '^ii.*cups'` to see all your installed CUPS packages. If some of them are at version `2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2`, revert them to version `2.1.3-4` with

```
sudo apt install package1=2.1.3-4 package2=2.1.3-4 ...
```

Comment: Why do you revert those packages to version `2.1.3-4` instead of upgrading everything to `2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2`? Will CUPS packages receive future upgrades automatically from Ubuntu package sources in the future in your case?

Comment: @XiaodongQi `2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2` has been withdrawn, the latest official version in 16.04 is now `2.1.3-4`, so people who upgraded to the former before it was withdrawn should revert to the latter. Of course, they will get future upgrades normally. (Alternatively, if `2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2` is not causing problems, one can also just stay on it and wait for a future upgrade, but it is causing problems to OP.)